# How to reference the one project to another

Tags: java, android, reference

I have one project called as A, I want to use that project with my B project, I don't want use entire code in B project I just want to use one xml file and related images in project B.

We can change values in that xml like any application names, images etc... is it possible?

Comment: Are you asking about Eclipse Android projects?

Comment: yes i am using eclipse

Answer (score 2):

You can do this

> Open Your Base Project B Right click on it go to Properties  then Android  Go to bottom Library - mark as Library.

Right click your project A (new project) in eclipse

Go to properties

Java Build path

From tabs Select Project

Click Add

Select your project B (Lib Project) you want to

Click Ok

Now you can use referenced project from your main project A.

Thanks.

[image: Setting for Project A (In Image for LibTest)]

Comment: Thanks Phanikanth for your +1.

Comment: Thank U rajinish,I did same but here problem is when we run the project B,i am expecting output of project A,but here getting output of proj B.

Comment: For example In project A output is Showing text Rajinish(that text is read from file in asset folder.),i want same output in project B(when i run project B).In project B also i read one file from asset folder here i changed text for differentiate between two outputs.Main theme is code re usability both projects content same but i change only names and images in scond project.

Comment: Make your project B (base project) as library project from properties/android/Library mark as library now you can use xml and resources from your base project into your new project  ie A

Comment: Thanks its not working for me. i want to control all names and images from One file.i kept that only one file in secondary project with some images stuff.

Comment: [link](http://i.imgur.com/OPvfbCp.png) got to this image and clear that you have these setting for Project A  (Like libTest) in image